# Difference between model_a.build_model_b vs. model_a.model_b.build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

A "user" has one "move". I want a user to edit their move on the "/user/(:id)/edit" page.

This means I have a nested form for a has_one relationship. If a "move" doesn't exist, then the nested part of the form will not display. To ensure one exists, you often see `@user.build_move` or `@user.move.build` in the controller.

My question is what is semantically different about `@user.build_move` and `@user.move.build`? The first one works fine, while the second returns an error `undefined method`build' for nil:NilClass`.

Here is example code:

In users#edit view

```
<%= form_for @user do |u| %>
  <p>Test A</p>
  <%= u.fields_for :move do |m| %>
    <p>Test B</p>
    <%= m.date :start_date %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In users#edit controller

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.move.build # Causes `undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass`
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this in your controller

```
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.build_move
end
```

`build` on association works only for `has_many` associations

For eg, if your `user has many roles`, you can say

```
@user.roles.build
```

But `@user.build_roles` will not work

Comment: Thanks @Vimsha, I understand that works. I'm curious how it is different from `@user.move.build`, and when to use each.

Comment: Interesting, will `@user.build_roles` work as well for a has_many?